# Uninstalling Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed Docker on my Unix machine and it was not working properly, so I tried to uninstall it to run through the steps again. I followed the uninstall steps here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#supported-storage-drivers

But I am receiving this error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  pigz slirp4netns
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  containerd.io* docker-ce* docker-ce-cli*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 138 not upgraded.
After this operation, 424 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 73672 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing docker-ce (5:20.10.3~3-0~ubuntu-focal) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping Docker: docker                                                      start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill 11177: No such process
No process in pidfile '/var/run/docker-ssd.pid' found running; none killed.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--remove):
 installed docker-ce package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How should I remove all the docker files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be related to GitHub issue posted on [here.](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1761)

Issue is related for line

```
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
```

Could you try to run uninstall again, as pure root?

```
sudo su
```

And attempt to remove then. If problem occurs still, there is another mentioned solution, related to `/etc/init.d/ebtables`. For some reason runlevel is unavailable. Suggested solution modifies this file as follows:

```
case "$1" in
    start)
        [ "$EBTABLES_LOAD_ON_START" = "yes" ] && load
        ;;
    stop)
        [ "$EBTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP" = "yes" ] && save
        clear
        ;;
```

Comment following lines:

```
stop)
    # [ "$EBTABLES_SAVE_ON_STOP" = "yes" ] && save
    # clear
    ;;
```

Answer (score 0):

To fully uninstall docker follow below commands:

- `dpkg -l | grep -i docker`
- `sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli`
- `sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce`

These commands will not remove the images, containers, volumes etc user created configuration files. So before deleting docker first delete these things. For deleting these things you can follow below commands:

- `docker rm -f (docker ps -a | awk '{print$1}')`: To delete all the docker container available in your machine
- `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`: To delete all the images, but before this you should remove all the containers which are created from this images
- `docker rm -vf $(docker ps -a -q)`: To delete all containers including its volumes uses

Comment: It should be good to point out, that images volumes etc. must be deleted before deleting Docker. Commands are not available afterwards.

Comment: @Niklas thanks for your comment, yes I should have mentioned that, now added.

Comment: `docker rm -f (docker ps -a | awk '{print$1}')` gives `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
```